# Is it possible to use icu4j UnicodeSet class for pattern matching instead of regex?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, icu

I've found [UnicodeSet](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/unicodeset) class of icu4j library in a [Java Regular expression library benchmark](http://www.tusker.org/regex/regex_benchmark.html) (*benchmarking source code: [regtest.java](http://www.tusker.org/regex/regtest.java)*). I'm trying to test it with the following code. It seems UnicodeSet has its own pattern syntax that is not fully compatible with PCRE.

```
String exp = "^[abc]x?c$";

com.ibm.icu.text.UnicodeSet uniset = new com.ibm.icu.text.UnicodeSet("[" + exp + "]");
java.util.regex.Pattern regex = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(exp);
System.out.println(uniset.containsAll("ac")); //Returns false
System.out.println(regex.matcher("ac").matches()); //Returns true
```

How to rewrite the above expression that will work properly with UnicodeSet?

I'm using ICU4J (49.1) library.

Answer (score 1):

`UnicodeSet` isn't a regex.  Your expression `[^[abc]x?c$]` matches a lot of codepoints, but `a` and `c` aren't among them.

http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp is a way to play with UnicodeSets online.

The benchmark page you mentioned ought to consider this.